# Is it possible to restriction-based modeling (like in FreeCAD) in Blender?

Tags: modeling, units

I am familiar to FreeCAD style modeling, which is mostly based on restrictions. But Blender uses another modeling logic.

So, is there some plugins or settings to make modeling style more like CAD? Have tried tinyCAD but it does not seems to be what I have been looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried CAD sketcher ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92QmjS-xDaI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this open source add-on [CAD Sketcher](https://makertales.gumroad.com/l/CADsketcher) is what I've been looking for. And thanks to [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) for mentioning that

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I used Draftsight (when there was a free version), but Has few tools.
I also tried to make parts for my 3D printer with 3D software, but there is no precision in tenths of millimeters, sheet thickness, etc. We cannot pretend that a 3D modeling software to work like a software based on 2D sketches and schematics.

Having said that, I suggest you look at **DesignSpark Mechanical**, which is the free version of **SpaceClaim**.

Comment: Thanks, although I am actually looking for a different modeling method for blender, rather than trying to do CAD with blender. But still thanks